# how to write a unit test that tests a global function

Tags: typescript, sinon

I have a function that's imported as such

```
import { queueCreateBitmap } from "@hz/tools-core";
```

I want to write a unit test that when `queueCreateBitmap` is called it throws an exception. How can I do that using sinon and typescript?

Comment: Sinon is a mocking framework. It doesn't provide testing assertions but merely adds onto an existing unit test framework, such as Mocha or Jest. What unit testing framework are you using? That will determine how to assert that an exception should be thrown.